# Extracting Sub-String using regex PHP

Tags: php, regex, substring

I have a need to extract a sub-string from a longer string.  I know how I would approach it using PHP posstr(); and strpos();, but the data is very large and I suspect that it would be more efficient if I could extract the part string using regex.

For example, if I have a number, (say a latitude) that has the format

```
"3203.79453"
```

where the the two characters before and "all" the characters after the decimal point represent decimal seconds, then to obtain the decimal latitude I need to compute the following:

```
32 + (03.79453)/60 = 32.06324217
```

So in essence I need a regex method of extracting the sub-string "03.79453".

So two questions how do I achieve it using regex and is it faster than using the method of  using strpos() and posstr().

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to achieve with both options:

```
substr($line, strpos($line, '.') - 2);
```

or:

```
preg_match("/(\d{2}\..*)/", $line, $matches);
```

As for performance, I guess you would need to benchmark it. I've done a quick test to compare the performance of each example by running one million reps of each of those lines:

- `preg_match`: [average](https://eval.in/623000) around 1.6 seconds for 1,000,000 matches
- `substr`: [average](https://eval.in/623001) around 0.85 seconds for 1,000,000 matches

In this case it seems clear that using `substr` is the winner in terms of performance.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks very much Robbie.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_replace()` like so:

```
    <?php

        $geoCoordinate  = "3203.79453";
        $degrees        = preg_replace("#(\d{2}\.\d*?$)#", "",          $geoCoordinate);
        $seconds        = preg_replace("#(\d*?)(\d{2}\.\d*?)#", "$2",   $geoCoordinate);
        $degAndSecs     = round($degrees + ($seconds/60), 8);

        var_dump($degAndSecs);  //<== PRODUCES::: float 32.06324217
```